# iMacros - Extract a part of text inside TD tag

Tags: screen-scraping, web-scraping, imacros

Please go to the link http://www.networksolutions.com/whois-search/reedandthomas.com

I want to extract only the below part of the text:

```
   Administrative Contact:
      Chilcoat, Dan  dchilcoat-rt@adelphia.net
      Reed & Thomas Electrical Contractors, Inc
      621 Hanover Pike
      Hampstead, Maryland 21074
      United States
      (410) 239-9680

   Technical Contact:
      Chilcoat, Dan  dchilcoat-rt@adelphia.net
      Reed & Thomas Electrical Contractors, Inc
      621 Hanover Pike
      Hampstead, Maryland 21074
      United States
      (410) 239-9680
```

and save it in an excel sheet with the Administrative Contact and Technical Contact details in each column.

I have worked on iMacros earlier and I know how to extract though. For another project I used

```
URL GOTO=http://www.yellowbook.com/yellow-pages/?what={{!COL2}}&where={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=6 TYPE=STRONG ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=d:\ FILE=results.txt
```

for extracting particular data from yellowbook.com

This whois extraction is a bit challenging for me because it is not the whole TD content I am after but a part of the TD content (only Administrative Contact and Technical Contact details). I am using iMacros browser addon for firefox. I also own a licensed copy of the iMacros browser in case your solution wants me to use it.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can use any scripting language to manipulate the extraction before saving it, if you have iMacros Scripting Interface.

However, recently a new feature has been introduced in both iMacros for Firefox and iMacros Browser (and the IE plugin) which allows one to manipulate the extracted string right in iMacros code, using javascript's eval.

I suggest you to have a look at http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL for the details.